# Is it possible to have one 'master' Django website and N satellite websites

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls

I am thinking of a configuration where I have one master website at:

www.masterdomain.com

and N satelite domains where I can access the satelite domains as follows:

www.masterdomain.com/some_url/satetlite1.html
www.masterdomain.com/some_url/satetlite2.html
...
www.masterdomain.com/some_url/satetliteN.html

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`sites` Framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) may interest you.

> Django comes with an optional “sites” framework. It’s a hook for associating objects and functionality to particular Web sites, and it’s a holding place for the domain names and “verbose” names of your Django-powered sites.
>
> Use it if your single Django installation powers more than one site and you need to differentiate between those sites in some way.

Also there are a couple of good blog post about that matter, e.g. this one:

- http://www.huyng.com/archives/franchising-running-multiple-sites-from-one-django-codebase-2/394/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and very useful reply + links. To be honest I am still reeling in shock that this can be done - as I had prepared myself for answers like "no - are you, crazy?, it can't be done!". My final question (now that I know it can be done), is that (hardware resources aside), is there any limit to how many satelite websites you can 'control' from the main website?. i.e. is there a limit on the size of N?

Comment: Your limits will be those of your webserver.

Comment: btw, your accept ratio is quite low; please, accept answers, that solved your problem or answered your question - it makes live easier for all of us.

Comment: The link you provided does not clarify whether one 'master' Django can be used to 'manage' multiple domains (e.g. domain1.com, domian2.com etc). Could you please clarify?